# 'basic' attribute type should not be Priority

Tags: java, hibernate

The below entity mapping I'd like to cast as a `Priority` object.  On the getter, when I change "Short" to "Priority" and follow suite with `this.priority` it complains that a `'basic' attribute type should not be priority`.  How can I set/get this as Priority?

```
@Column(name = "priority", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 5, precision = 0)
public Short getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

public void setPriority(Short priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}
```

My Priority class:

```
public class Priority {
    public static final Priority TOP = new Priority("TOP", 100);

    public static final Priority PRIORITY_REMAN = new Priority("PRIORITY_REMAN", 250);

    public static final Priority PRIORITY = new Priority("PRIORITY", 500);

    public static final Priority STANDARD_REMAN = new Priority("STANDARD_REMAN", 750);

    public static final Priority STANDARD = new Priority("STANDARD", 1000);

    private final String name;
    private final Integer value;

    public Priority() {
        this.name = null;
        this.value = 0;
    }

    protected Priority(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonView({Views.ShutdownView.class})
    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the column defined in the DB ?

Comment: make it an enum and use @Enumerated. or make a custom UserType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `Priority` class to `Enum` and also change your `getPriority` method to something like this:

```
@Enumerated
@Column(name = "priority", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 5, precision = 0)
public PriorityEnum getPriority() {
    return priority;
}
```

This way, the hibernate will try to save `Priority` property in database as a number representing order of given value in `Enumeration` definition. So if the value of the `priority` property is TOP, corresponding value in database would be `1`, if it's `PRIORITY_REMAN`, the value in database would be `2` and so on.

In order to change this behavior, you can change the `@Enumerated` annotation to

`@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`

In this case, the corresponding column in database should be some sort of `String` (like `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`), because hibernate would try to save the string value of `TOP` or `PRIORITY_REMAN` in database.

Answer (score 0):

you can't, Short is a final class, so you can't extend it.

what i suggest you to do is to create another getter that you need, something like :

```
public Priority getJsonPriority() {
    return new Priority(this.priority);
}
```

or make Priority.class as Persistent Entity, and add OneToOne relation to it, which is not the best solution for you..